# .trigger('click'); not working on mobile or syntax in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, eventtrigger

I wrote a simple function which works perfectly on PC but not on mobile. Whenever I tap on `.link p` it doesn't fire `trigger('click')`. Maybe the problem lies somwhere else, but I can't localise it. Help would much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="galeria">
<div class="gallery">
    <figure class="gallery-item">
        <div class="gallery-icon portrait">
            <a data-caption="" href="">
                <img/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption">Etykieta</figcaption>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="link">
            <p>Whatever</p>
        </div>
    </figure>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $container = jQuery('.galeria')
jQuery('.galeria').isotope({
itemSelector: '.galeria .gallery',
layoutMode: 'masonry',
});

jQuery('.galeria .gallery-item').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');

jQuery('.galeria .gallery').each(function() {
var text = jQuery(this).find('.gallery-item:first-child .gallery-caption').text();
jQuery(this).find('.gallery-item').append('<div class="link"><p>'+text+'</p></div>');
});

var marginTop = jQuery('.link').height();
jQuery('.link').css('margin-top',-marginTop/2)


// here is the function I'm concerned about, but maybe the problem is somwhere else
jQuery('.link p').on('click touchstart',function() {
jQuery(this).closest('.gallery-item').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

I think I gave you guys all the info needed, if you need more ask instead of minusing me, pls. Regards.

----EDIT----

[Here](https://jogownia.pl/galeria/) is the link leading to the website the code is put on.

----EDIT 2 ----

Ok, I didn't describe what I need it to do. Normally the link `a` in `.gallery-icon` opens a lightbox gallery when you click on it. But I wanted to create another clickable element somwhere else to make CSS styling more sophisticated (animations, overlays, etc.), that's why above function appends another div `.link` with clickable `p` inside. After clicking `p` mentioned `a` link is being triggered. When I delete all the functions creating additional divs and triggering links tapping `a` directly is working properly on mobiles.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not full, so I may be wrong when try to understand it, but I think your problem is that you try to trigger "click" event on `<a>` element to redirect user to another page.

If you meant to do that you should use following code (in your 'click touchstart' event):

```
window.location.href = jQuery(this).closest('.gallery-item').find('a').attr('href');
```

-- EDIT --

As I checked you site it is possible that your link (**.link a**) element is not visible on mobile devices as it shows only when cursor is hovering **.gallery-item**.

Best solution for mobile devices is to assign event to element that user can see in browser without hovering anything (eg. **.gallery-item** or **.overlay**).

-- EDIT 2 --

As I mentioned before, you should assign an event to element that user can see in mobile browser without hovering over anything (as on mobile browser it is impssible).

You can do it like this:

```
jQuery('.gallery-item').on('click touchstart',function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.gallery-item').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

if the code will not work with **.gallery-item** that you have to use other selector that points to element visible by user and is on top (over other elements on page).

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out, there is another edit describing what I really meant by creating all of those functions. Thanks.